# Html.Kendo().DropDownList() ".text()" not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo DropdDownList which seems to work fine, it takes the list of items from the ViewData and displays them perfectly.

```
.BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["modulos"])
.DataTextField("Codmodulo")
```

Then I call the controller (via TypeScript) and try to pass him the text of the selected item, something like this:

```
Codmodulo: $("#funcionesDropDownList").text()
```

But for some reason, that always returns an empty string (""), while

```
Codmodulo: $("#funcionesDropDownList").val()
```

works fine and gives me the desired value. This was working fine for me yesterday. Any ideas what could be wrong?

English is not my first language, feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#funcionesDropDownList")` is hidden input HTML element of the Drop Down List and it holds it's value.

The `text()` method returns text placed inside DOM element on which you invoke it. So if you invoke it for the element without inner text like:

```
<input id="funcionesDropDownList" value="abc" data-role="dropdownlist"
style="display: none;" />
```

you'll get empty text.

The `val()` method retutns value of the element's value attribute element (in this case abc) therefore it returns correct value.

To get value of the Drop Down List, using KendoUI API, you can use this code:

```
var listValue = $("#funcionesDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
```

You can read about about the API on the [KendoUI site](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-value).

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery specification](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

`.text()`

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements

and `.val()`

> Get the current value of the first element in the set

`DropdDownList` generate `input` html element and inputs don't have contents. Text is stored in value.
If you want to get text from other (non form) tags, you can use text() function.

Comment: This is what I was trying, but is not working for me. I've seen that $("#funcionesDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList").text(); works, but I'm pretty sure that only $("#funcionesDropDownList").text(); worked fine for me yesterday

Comment: So now your val() function gives you an empty string? Your question is unclear. Give me html code generated by this Razor.

Comment: val() was always working fine, $("#funcionesDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList").text(); is what I had to do, @jarosław-kończak explained it really good